# Angular: Possible to use PWA on development server (ng serve)?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, production-environment, angular9

I'm working on an application where I'm using PWA for the first time and I'm trying to work with push notifications etc.

Currently I have PWA working if I execute the following commands `ng build --prod` and `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/myProject`, but I was wondering if there was a way to have PWA work on `ng serve` so that I don't constantly have to build the project because that takes quite some time.

EDIT: Added information

I tried modifying the `serve` object in `angular.json` by adding

```
            "assets": [
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
```

to the `options` attribute but this gives the error `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets)` so I suppose that this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Because ng serve does not work with service workers, you must use a separate HTTP server to test your project locally.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server

Basically you can develop your app using the `ng serve` but you can't install it or have updates when using `ng serve`. For that purposes you have to use the `http-server`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed the http-server command to ```http-server -p 8080 -c-1 src``` yet now I get multiple 404 errors (on ngsw-worker). Is this avoidable or not?

Comment: @RubenSzekér It looks like you forgot to attach the path to your command try `http-server ./dist -p 8080 -c-1 src` and also you have to build your app as well using `ng build` so the files would appear in the dist folder for you to serve them,

Comment: @NerijusPamedytis if you read my original post then you'll see that I can indeed run the builded project, but the problem with always having to build the project is that it takes a lot of time between every time I want to test it. So that's why I was wondering if there was a way to make it work on the unbuild version that is used in ```ng serve```

Comment: Unfortunately, the quoted text is no longer in the linked docs. 
There is only one reference to `http-server` that I can find on the linked page and it is in a console command with no other explanation.
I can confirm service workers are not working via ng serve, though on Angular 16.